# Prevent validation when you have hide field Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am doing an airline reservation and I have 2 radio button.

1) One way

2) Round Trip

The things that I've done is when I select the Round Trip, all the fields are there(Depart, return and number of passengers) but I when select One way radio button the return field should hide.

In my controller, I have validation that all fields are required. The problem is, whenever I tried to search in One Way(the return field is hidden) it gives me an "Return field is required" error

Question: How can I prevent the validation in return field when I choice the One Way radio button?

**View**

```
<div class="pure-u-1-1 searchcontainer center">
            <div class="pure-u-1-1 findcheaptxt">
               <span>Find Cheap Flights</span>
            </div>
            <div class="pure-u-1-1 radiobtn">
               <form action="">
                  <input type="radio" name="flight_type"  value="one_way" class="onew" style=""  >One Way
                  <input type="radio" name="flight_type" class="roundw" style="" checked>Round Trip
               </form>
            </div>

            <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?= base_url() .'User/search'?>">
            <?= validation_errors(); ?>
            <div class="pure-u-1-1 fromto">
               <div class="pure-u-1-1">
                  <label for="from" class="margin2px">From</label>

                  <select name="flight_from">
                    <option value="">-- Please select depature --</option>   
                    <?php foreach($countries as $country):?>
                        <option value ="<?= $country->country_name?>" ><?= $country->country_name?></option>
                    <?php endforeach?>

                  </select>

               </div>
                <div class="pure-u-1-1">
                  <label for="to" class="tomargin">To</label>
                  <!-- <input type="text" class="fromto"><br> -->
                  <select class="fromto" name="flight_to">
                    <option value="">-- Please select destination --</option>
                    <?php foreach($countries as $country):?>
                        <option value ="<?= $country->country_name?>" ><?= $country->country_name?></option>
                    <?php endforeach?>
                  </select>
                </div>
               <div class="pure-u-1-1 dr" name ="depart">
                  <label for="depart" class="drr">Depart</label>
                  <input type="date" id="depart" name="depart" class="departreturn">

               </div>
                <div class="pure-u-1-1 dr" id="try">
                  <label for="return" class="drr">Return</label>
                  <input type="date" id="return" name="return" class="departreturn"><br>

                  </div>
            </div>

            <div class="pure-u-1-1 personfield">
                <!--  <div class="pure-u-1-5 margin">
                    Adult<br>
                    <input type="text" name="" class="person">
                 </div>
                 <div class="pure-u-1-5 margin">
                    Seniors<br>
                    <input type="text" name="" class="person">
                 </div>
                 <div class="pure-u-1-5 margin">
                    Children<br>
                    <input type="text" name="" class="person">
                 </div>
                 <div class="pure-u-1-5">
                    Class<br>
                    <input type="text" name="" class="person">
                 </div> -->
                  <div class="pure-u-1-5 margin">
                    Number of Passengers<br>
                    <input type="text" name="no_of_passengers" class="person">
                 </div>

            </div>
                 <div class="pure-u-1-1 center">
                      <button class="submitbtn">Search Now</button>
               </form>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
```

**Controller**

```
public function search()
{
    $data['countries'] = $this->CrudModel->get('countries');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">', '</div>');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('flight_from', 'Select depature', 'required|trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('flight_to', 'Select Destination', 'required|trim');

    if ($_POST['flight_type'] == 'round_trip')
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('depart', 'Date of flight', 'required|trim');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('return', 'Date of return', 'required|trim');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('no_of_passengers', 'Number of Passengers', 'required');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->index();

        }
        else
        {
            $search_result = array(
                $flight_from = $_POST['flight_from'],
                $flight_to = $_POST['flight_to'],
                $depart = $_POST['depart'],
                $return = $_POST['return'],
                $no_of_passengers = $_POST['no_of_passengers']
            );
            $data['search_result'] = $this->CrudModel->search('flight',$flight_from,$flight_to,$depart,$return,$no_of_passengers);
            $this->load->view('partials/header');
            $this->load->view('partials/nav');
            $this->load->view('result',$data);
        } 

    }
    else
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('depart', 'Date of flight', 'required|trim');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('no_of_passengers', 'Number of Passengers', 'required');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->index();

        }
        else {
            $search_result = array(
                $flight_from = $_POST['flight_from'],
                $flight_to = $_POST['flight_to'],
                $depart = $_POST['depart'],
                $no_of_passengers = $_POST['no_of_passengers']
            );
        $data['search_result'] = $this->CrudModel->search('flight',$flight_from,$flight_to,$depart,$no_of_passengers);
        $this->load->view('partials/header');
        $this->load->view('partials/nav');
        $this->load->view('result',$data);
        }

    }
}
```

**My ajax/js when hiding the return field**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('change', 'input:radio[name=flight_type]', function(){
    $('div[id^="try"]').toggle(); // hide all DIVs begining with "my_radio_"
    $('#' + $(this).attr('id') + '_text').show(); // show the current one
});
</script>
```

Comment: you does havn't add value for round trip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you have to add value to round trip:

```
 <input type="radio" name="flight_type" value="round_trip" class="roundw" style="" checked>Round Trip
```

Then do validation condition like below:

```
  // Global validation for this method
 if ($_POST['flight_type'] == 'round_trip')
   {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('depart', 'Date of flight', 'required|trim');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('return', 'Date of return', 'required|trim');
   }
   else if($_POST['flight_type'] == 'one_way'){
       // add validation for one way trip
   }
```

Comment: Hi sir, why is that I need to put a value="round_trip"? I mean the others is only need is name=" * "..

Comment: Its because if you checked round trip and submit form you can't get  $_POST['flight_type'] that's why you have to add. check out this simple page https://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_form_validation_complete.

Comment: Hi sir, I'm having an error "Message: Undefined index: flight_type" controller/User line 28.. What is my mistake? I updated my post

Comment: $flight_type = $this->input->post("flight_type"); try this and echo it also still i can't find value in rounf trip

Comment: I have figured it out my mistake, I didnt include the radio button inside of a form lol.. Sorry my bad lol

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass `flight_type` parameters in post request. Then your code will be something like this describe below.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('flight_from', 'Select depature', 'required|trim');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('depart', 'Date of flight', 'required|trim');

if($this->input->post('flight_type')== 'roundw'):
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('flight_to', 'Select Destination', 'required|trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('return', 'Date of return', 'required|trim');
endif:
```

Let me know if it not works for you.

Comment: Can you please share your model search function. because it seems like you have some error in model part.

Comment: As @ahmed ginani said, you can't get $_POST['flight_type'] that's why I need to add value in my view